# Java Rest API: how to check connection between client and endpoint?

Tags: java, rest, jax-rs

How I can check if user who sent rest request aborted it using Ctrl-C?
I need to check it on server side because it takes several minutes. If user aborted it then I should stop it.

I tried to write to ServletOutputStream but it doesn't work (I never catch exception):

```
@Path("test")
public void test(@Context MessageContext mc) {
  try {
     ServletOutputStream out = mc.getHttpServletResponse().getOutputStream();
     out.println("test");
     out.flush();
  } catch (IOException e) {
     System.out.println("Connection is broken");
     return;
  }
}
```

Found solution:

```
    private boolean isConnected() {
    try {
        servletResponse.getOutputStream().println("data");
        servletResponse.flushBuffer();
        return true;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please show us [what you have tried](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/) so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
private boolean isConnected() {
    try {
        servletResponse.getOutputStream().println("data");
        servletResponse.flushBuffer();
        return true;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please edit your question with the solution and not answer your question yourselfe

Comment: @Developer66, This practice is actually encouraged, https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer