# Checking of REST connection before returning data from REST server

Tags: java, spring, rest, http

I use Spring framework for creating REST HTTP server.

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/message")
public class MessageRequest {

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public @ResponseBody String doPost(
        @PathVariable String param
    ) {
        /*do something */
        return "answer";
    }
}
```

I need to check connection before sending response to a client. If client was disconnected (example by read timeout), then answer will be sending via another way. How can i check connection before returning of response?

Comment: That does not sound like REST to me.  REST is idempotent - no knowledge of clients.

Comment: I think HTTP won't help you with that. Have you considered Websockets?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java Rest API: how to check connection between client and endpoint?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17523118/java-rest-api-how-to-check-connection-between-client-and-endpoint)

Comment: HTTP is not a connection oriented protocol.